# How to replace unique values with list in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
Data: df
 neighbourhood_group   neighbourhood <br>
     Brooklyn               by1 <br>
     Bronx                  bx1 <br>
     Brooklyn               by2 <br>
     Manhattan              mn1 <br>
     Bronx                  bx1 <br>
     Bronx                  bx3 <br>
     Manhattan              mn2 <br>
     Manhattan              mn1 <br>
     Brooklyn               by1 <br>
     Brooklyn               by2 <br>
```

I wanted the data to include 2 new columns ngp_id and n_id, where ngp_id= unique(neighbourhood_group with values 1:n, where n is the total unique values), and n_id= unique(neighbourhood with values 1:n). In my data, id2 has about 277 unique ids.

Question: I tried to add 2 columns by using dplyr, which I succeeded, but I needed the resultant data to be grouped these two columns first by ngp_id and then by n_id. I mean the final result should be as below, please guide me as to how I could achieve this.

```
ngp_id n_id neighbourhood_group neighbourhood <br>
    1   1   Brooklyn    by1 <br>
    1   1   Brooklyn    by1 <br>
    1   3   Brooklyn    by2 <br>
    1   3   Brooklyn    by2 <br>
    2   2   Bronx       bx1 <br>
    2   2   Bronx       bx1 <br>
    2   5   Bronx       bx3 <br>
    3   4   Manhattan   mn1 <br>
    3   4   Manhattan   mn1 <br>
    3   6   Manhattan   mn2 <br>
```

My code:

```
g_id= c(1:10)

neighbourhood_group= c("Brooklyn","Bronx","Brooklyn","Manhattan", "Bronx","Bronx","Manhattan","Manhattan", "Brooklyn","Brooklyn")

neighbourhood= c("by1", "bx1","by2","mn1","bx1","bx3","mn2","mn1","by1", "by2" )

df <- data.frame(g_id, neighbourhood_group,neighbourhood) 
df1 <- df %>% 
     mutate(neighbourhood_group=factor(neighbourhood_group,levels = unique(neighbourhood_group), ordered = T), 
                   neighbourhood=factor(neighbourhood,levels = unique(neighbourhood), ordered = T)) %>%
       group_by(neighbourhood_group) %>% 
       mutate(id == cur_group_id()) %>% 
       ungroup() %>% 
       group_by(neighbourhood) %>% 
       mutate(id2=cur_group_id()) %>% 
       ungroup() %>%
       mutate(neighbourhood_group=as.integer(as.character(neighbourhood_group)),
       neighbourhood=as.integer(as.character(neighbourhood)))
```

Comment: Not sure how you are calculating `n_id` ? How the values are 4, 4 and 6 for `ngp_id = 3` ?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Coerce the `factor(neighbourhood_group)` and `factor(neighbourhood)` to numeric (integer) and assign to new id names `ngp_id` `n_id` and then `arrange`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
dat1 <- read.table(text="neighbourhood_group neighbourhood
                          Brooklyn by1
                          Bronx bx1
                          Brooklyn by2
                          Manhattan mn1
                          Bronx bx1
                          Bronx bx3
                          Manhattan mn2
                          Manhattan mn1
                          Brooklyn by1
                          Brooklyn by2", header=T)
dat1 %>%  
  mutate(ngp_id = as.numeric(factor(neighbourhood_group)),
         n_id = as.numeric(factor(neighbourhood))) %>%
  arrange(ngp_id, n_id)
#>    neighbourhood_group neighbourhood ngp_id n_id
#> 1                Bronx           bx1      1    1
#> 2                Bronx           bx1      1    1
#> 3                Bronx           bx3      1    2
#> 4             Brooklyn           by1      2    3
#> 5             Brooklyn           by1      2    3
#> 6             Brooklyn           by2      2    4
#> 7             Brooklyn           by2      2    4
#> 8            Manhattan           mn1      3    5
#> 9            Manhattan           mn1      3    5
#> 10           Manhattan           mn2      3    6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry I mentioned it worked, actually I am seeing an issue in the final output. The n_id is being reset to 1. What I mean is  bx1, bx3, by1,by2, mn1, mn2 are all showing n_id as 1 and rest as 2. Actually I need them to display as unique(neighbourhood) as factor(neighbourhood) so that bx1=1, bx3=2, by1=3, by2=4, mn1=5, mn2=6. Pleas suggest

Comment: Kris4u, check the updated reprex. Is that what you want? I misunderstood it seems. You don't need to group.

Comment: Or alternately: `mutate(dat1, across(.fns = function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)), .names = "id_{.col}"))`  to more clearly show the id:factor label relationship